# First row dropped in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with the following values. In the csv file, there is no header. I have the code as:

```
df = pd.read_csv(latestfile, header=None)
```

Since the script looks for the latest file in a specific folder, I am calling latestfile. Below is what is shown when I do a print function. When I call the function to output the file to another csv and add headers, the top most row is dropped. Is there something additional that I need to add to have the top most row outputted? This is the output code:

```
my_filtered_csv.to_csv('E:\Test\my_filtered_csv.csv', header=["MID", "DID"], index=False)
```

```
       7619623       Y8G029224 
0      7619627       Y1G029224  
1      7619629           35200
```

Here is the code:

```
    import pysftp
import os
import pandas as pd


# Accept any host key (still wrong see below)
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys=None
# And authenticate with private key
sftp = pysftp.Connection(
  host="test.sftp.net", username="test", password="test123", cnopts=cnopts) #private_key=".ppk", 

# Temporary change directory
sftp.cwd('/delivery_files/')

# Get latest file
latest = 0
latestfile = None

for fileattr in sftp.listdir_attr():
    if fileattr.filename.startswith('Report_') and fileattr.st_mtime > latest:
        latest = fileattr.st_mtime
        latestfile = fileattr.filename

if latestfile is not None:
    sftp.get(latestfile, latestfile)

df = pd.read_csv(latestfile, header=None)
df.rename(columns={0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: 'MID', 5: 'DID', 6: '7', inplace = True)

my_filtered_csv = pd.read_csv (latestfile, usecols=[4,5])
 

my_filtered_csv.to_csv('E:\Test\my_filtered_csv.csv', header=["MID", "DID"], index=False)




# Closes the connection
sftp.close()

# Prints out the directories and files, line by line

#print latestfile
print my_filtered_csv
```

Comment: 7619623       Y8G029224
0      7619627       Y1G029224  
1      7619629           35200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work.

Are you potentially re-opening the csv file that you just saved with the command `pd.read_csv('E:\Test\my_filtered_csv.csv', header=None)` ?

If so, as you re-use `header=None`, the new header will not show as you re-open the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Your data shows that the first line --  7619623 Y8G029224 -- is not data since the second line has index 0, third line has index 1. So the output is not ignoring any data. So the only issue is what is the first line in the print. We can try to figure it out for you if you paste code.

Comment: The first line is data. It is the same report information that is indicated by 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

I added header=None in this line, and it appears to work now.

my_filtered_csv = pd.read_csv (latestfile, header=None, usecols=[4,5])